# depth map extraction from single image

Tags: algorithm, opencv, image-processing

please help me.

I'm looking for a simple algorithm that its input is a single image and that's it. The output will be a depth map of the image with colors of pixels according to if they are near or far from the camera.
I am looking for a simple solution without Machine Learning, 3D model, sterioscopic input or user input help. Only a single image.

thank you

Comment: Do you really understand what you're asking? This isn't a simple task in the first place. Why don't you want to use any _tool_ that can help to solve the problem?

Comment: According to your conditions I'm afraid that such algorithm doesn't exist. Try at least stereo. This approach is simple enough.

Comment: The only solution of your problem is random. How it can be possible without machine learning? There are some methods like depth transfer and make3D which estimate the depth based on similar depth candidates in terms of spatial and semantic characteristics. Otherwise, use trangulation equations if you know the parameters of your camera and the relations between pixels in the 3D space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are asking is in general an ill posed problem.
However, recent work with deep-networks have shown that a depth map can be predicted from a single image.

Here's one such paper: [Depth Map Prediction from a Single Image
using a Multi-Scale Deep Network](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/5539-depth-map-prediction-from-a-single-image-using-a-multi-scale-deep-network.pdf).

From the abstract:

> Predicting depth is an essential component in understanding the 3D
>   geometry of a scene. While for stereo images local correspondence
>   suffices for estimation, finding depth relations from a single image
>   is less straightforward, requiring integration of both global and
>   local information from various cues. Moreover, the task is inherently
>   ambiguous, with a large source of uncertainty coming from the overall
>   scale. In this paper, we present a new method that addresses this task
>   by employing two deep network stacks: one that makes a coarse global
>   prediction based on the entire image, and another that refines this
>   prediction locally. We also apply a scale-invariant error to help
>   measure depth relations rather than scale. By leveraging the raw
>   datasets as large sources of training data, our method achieves
>   state-of-the-art results on both NYU Depth and KITTI, and matches
>   detailed depth boundaries without the need for superpixelation.

Comment: The new version of photoshop does this now from a single image. Seems really cool. I wonder if there is an open source way to do this.

Comment: This problem is also known as "monocular depth estimation."